# Odoo specific form view on many2many field

Tags: python, python-2.7, view, odoo, odoo-9

I have many2many field:

```
supply_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='supply.conditions',
                                          relation='purchase_supply_rel',
                                          column1='purchase_requests_id', column2='supply_conditions_id',
                                          string='Supply Conditions')
```

and piece of xml

```
 <page string="Order">
        <field name="supply_ids"/>
 </page>
```

I have only one supply.conditions form view but I want create another one (with less fields) and show it on supply_ids field click:

```
"Add object" -> "Create"
```

I don't know what method is called on "Add object" click or how can I select specific form view on "Add object" -> "Create" button..

Answer (score 7):

Create a second form view with like

```xml
<record id="view_supply_conditions_form2" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">...</field>
    <field name="model">supply.conditions</field>
    <field name="priority">17</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- and so on -->
    </field>
</record>
```

And then call it on your field with context:

```xml
<page string="Order">
    <field name="supply_ids"
        context="{'form_view_ref':'my_module.view_supply_conditions_form2'}"/>
</page>
```

**Edit:**

The corresponding context keys for list and search views are `tree_view_ref` and `search_view_ref`.

Thanks to @Fractalf

Comment: Thank you! I want to add that if the field you want to display differently is a tree view, you must use `tree_view_ref`, likewise with a search view: `search_view_ref`

Comment: how can we set ref of form view for each different row of m2m field ?

Comment: @Naitik i think that is not possible. Another way would be some field on a row which influences the appearance of a form view. So let's say their is a field "type" which show some fields on value "type1" but hides other fields and likewise with other values. It will be the same form view but with other appearances depending on the "type" field.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, added context to field:

```
 <page string="Order">
        <field name="supply_ids" context="{'form_view_ref':'my_app_name.view_supply_conditions_form'}"/>/>
 </page>
```

**view_supply_conditions_form** - new form view